# Need to print out largest prime factor in a do while loop

Tags: java

I want the following code to print out only the largest prime factor for the number. As you can see, where I have my `println` it is in the while loop and prints out both 2 and 3. Would someone please tell me how I could insert a `println` in the code to only print out the largest prime factor, not both. No matter which other places in the code I insert the `println` I either get both 2 and 3, or if outside the while loop I get 4 which I understand why 4, but realize 4 is incorrect. If this can't be done I will not use the `do while` loop. Thanks.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Using a do while loop to determine the largest prime factor of a number
        //and only wanting to print out the largest prime factor.
        int i = 2;
        int number = 36;
        int largestPrimeFactor = 0;
        for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                largestPrimeFactor = i;
            }
            do {
                number /= i;
            } while (number % i == 0);
            System.out.println(i + " is the largest prime factor");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `continue` the `for` loop if `number % i == 0` is `false`.
2. Print `largestPrimeFactor`, not `i`.
3. The print statement needs to be put outside the `for` loop.

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 39, largestPrimeFactor = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                largestPrimeFactor = i;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
            do {
                number /= i;
            } while (number % i == 0);
        }
        System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor + " is the largest prime factor");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
13 is the largest prime factor
```

Comment: Arvind, thank you for the clarity. First off i should have noticed that I was printing i instead of largestPrimeFactor. Second, is the reason you stated to "do it as follows" is because your code is cleaner than mine?  Thanks.  I may be a novice but it is my hope to be able to write clean code from the beginning.

Comment: @RonRoberts -You are most welcome. I've suggested three changes in your code and I thought it would be helpful for you if I post the code incorporating all my suggestions. That is the reason why I've stated, `Do it as follows`. Your code is as clean as mine but without these changes, you won't get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Largest Factor .

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargetPrimeFactor{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.printf("Largest prime factor of number '%d' is %d %n",
                6, largestPrimeFactor(6));
        System.out.printf("highest prime factor of number '%d' is %d %n",
                15, largestPrimeFactor(15));
        System.out.printf("Biggest prime factor of number '%d' is %d %n",
                392832, largestPrimeFactor(392832));
        System.out.printf("Largest prime factor of number '%d' is %d %n",
                1787866, largestPrimeFactor(1787866));
    }

    public static int largestPrimeFactor(long number) {
        int i;
        long copyOfInput = number;

        for (i = 2; i <= copyOfInput; i++) {
            if (copyOfInput % i == 0) {
                copyOfInput /= i;
                i--;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Largest prime factor of number '6' is 3
highest prime factor of number '15' is 5
Biggest prime factor of number '392832' is 31
Largest prime factor of number '1787866' is 893933
```